# What is mutex_wrapped?

Tags: c++

In this [tutorial](https://devtut.github.io/cpp/lambdas.html#generic-lambdas) they state:

> A strong reason to use generic lambdas is for visiting syntax.
>
> ```
> boost::variant<int, double> value;
> apply_visitor(value, [&](auto&& e){
>   std::cout << e;
> });
> ```
>
> Here we are visiting in a polymorphic manner; but in other contexts,
> the names of the type we are passing isn't interesting:
>
> ```
> mutex_wrapped<std::ostream&> os = std::cout;
> os.write([&](auto&& os){
>   os << "hello world\n";
> });
> ```
>
> Repeating the type of std::ostream& is noise here; it would be like
> having to mention the type of a variable every time you use it. Here
> we are creating a visitor, but no a polymorphic one; auto is used for
> the same reason you might use auto in a for(:) loop.

First of all I could not get the above example to work with out swapping the operands around:

```
boost::variant<int, double> value;
boost::apply_visitor(
    [&](auto&& e){
        std::cout << e;
    },
    value
);
```

I suppose this could be due to changes to boost since the tutorial was written.

But for the second example I cannot yet find from where `mutex_wrapped` comes, and I do not understand what `write(lambda)` will do, it seems to me that `write()` requires `const char* s, streamsize n`.

Is this second example purely imaginary as in mutex_wrapped is an imaginary class that has a write method that takes a lambda and executes the lambda using the wrapped stream as the parameter?

Comment: `mutex_wrapped` is quite clearly a general wrapper around an object. `write` is not related to `ostream` in particular but a call to the operation on the managed object. `write` will supply the object by reference, while `read` supplies by const reference. Also all read/writes internally lock/unlock the mutex.

Comment: @Motomotes Why have you changed your decision and accepted the answer that can't be compiled with the code in your question? The error is: `error: no viable conversion from 'ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') to 'mutex_wrapped<std::ostream &>' (aka 'mutex_wrapped<basic_ostream<char> &>')\n
    mutex_wrapped<std::ostream&> os = std::cout;` That answer changed your code to `mutex_wrapped<std::ostream&> os(std::cout);`

Comment: The other answer was first and made the needed correction to the example, `mutex_wrapped<std::ostream&> os(std::cout);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wrapper needs a generic constructor to assign it's internal type `T`, `t` variable. Here's a complete corrected example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <shared_mutex>
    
template<class T>
struct mutex_wrapped {
    explicit mutex_wrapped(T t) : t(t) {}

    template<class F>
    auto read( F&& f ) const {
        auto l = lock();
        return f(t);
    }
    template<class F>
    auto write( F&& f ) {
        auto l = lock();
        return f(t);
    }
private:
    mutable std::shared_mutex m;
    T t = {};
    auto lock() const { return std::shared_lock< std::shared_mutex >( m ); }
    auto lock() { return std::unique_lock< std::shared_mutex >( m ); }
};

int main() {
    mutex_wrapped<std::ostream&> os(std::cout);
    os.write([&](auto&& os){
        os << "hello world\n";
    });

    return 0;
}
```

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: Even copying and fixing another answer, you managed to insert absolutely unnecessary [`using namespace std;` that is considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: @273K My answer was submitted 5 seconds prior to one's edit containing the constructor, I tried the example in CLion which includes using...std in the default project template.

Answer (score 0):

[Declaimer](https://devtut.github.io/cpp/) of that site:

> This Tutorial is compiled from StackOverflow Documentation, the content is written by the brilliant people at Stack Overflow.

Googling trough StackOverflow gave me that posted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59601498/6752050. It defined `shared_mutex_wrapped` but the example used it as `mutex_wrapped`, it might be a typo. Let's name it `mutex_wrapped`:

```
template<class T>
struct mutex_wrapped {
  mutex_wrapped(T t) : t(t) {}  // Was missing in the original post

  template<class F>
  auto read( F&& f ) const {
    auto l = lock();
    return f(t);
  }

  template<class F>
  auto write( F&& f ) {
    auto l = lock();
    return f(t);
  }

private:
  mutable std::shared_mutex m;
  T t = {};
  auto lock() const { return std::shared_lock< std::shared_mutex >( m ); }
  auto lock() { return std::unique_lock< std::shared_mutex >( m ); }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw that briefly from searching earlier but noticed it was `shared_mutex_wrapper`, yet it was used as `mutex_wrapper` in the example on the other answer as well, so I went ahead and tried it but it gives an error like "no viable conversion between basic_stream... and mutex_wrapper..." So even with the above definition the example still does not work.

Comment: Because it is missing a constructor, that you could easy add. See the update.